# PHP-FPM doesn't write to error log

Tags: php

I've just installed a nginx+php-fpm server. Everything seems fine except that PHP-FPM never writes error to its log.

fpm.conf

```
[default]
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/default.sock
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = webusr
listen.group = webusr
listen.mode = 0666
user = webusr
group = webusr
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
pm.status_path = /php/fpm/status
ping.path = /php/fpm/ping
request_terminate_timeout = 30s
request_slowlog_timeout = 10s
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/default/slow.log
chroot = /var/www/sites/webusr
catch_workers_output = yes
env[HOSTNAME] = mapsvr.mapking.com
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/default/error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

nginx.conf

```
server
{
  listen        80 default_server;
  server_name   _;

  charset       utf-8;
  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log rest;

  include       conf.d/drops.conf.inc;

  location      /
  {
    root        /var/www/sites/webusr/htdocs;
    index       index.html index.htm index.php;
  }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on socket
  #
  location      ~ \.php$
  {
    root           /var/www/sites/webusr/htdocs;
    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /htdocs/$fastcgi_script_name;
    if (-f $request_filename)
    {
      fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock;
    }
  }

  location      = /php/fpm/status
  {
    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock;
  }

  location      = /php/fpm/ping
  {
    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock;
  }

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  #
  error_page    500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location      = /50x.html
  {
    root        /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

I've made an erroneous php script and run, and see error output on the web browser. Also nginx error log states stderr output from fpm with the same message. I've check that the user have write (I've even tried 777) permission to the appointed log folder. Even the appointed error.log file has be created successfully by php-fpm. However, the log file is always empty, no matter what outrageous error has been made from php script.

What's going on?

[Found the reason quite a while later]

It was permission. Changed the owner to the sites's users solved the problem.

Comment: It worth to mention that problematic php version is between v5.3.9 and v5.3.14 (as on today). It should work starting from v5.3.15 and v5.4.5.

Comment: if you're using hhvm + php-fpm with homestead the log is at tail /var/log/hhvm/error.log

Comment: Same problem here. It seems like the access and slow log need different permissions, thus the folder is created with root-755.

Answer (score 223):

This worked for me:

```
; Redirect worker stdout and stderr into main error log. If not set, stdout and
; stderr will be redirected to /dev/null according to FastCGI specs.
; Default Value: no
catch_workers_output = yes
```

Edit:

The file to edit is the file that configure your desired pool.
By default its: /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

Comment: <strike>In what config file? php.ini? php-fpm.conf?</strike>. I uncommented it inside my `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

Comment: On Ubuntu 14 this file is located at /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

Comment: I guess the question then is where this elusive "main error log" is...  Oh, I see, it's the value of `php_admin_value[error_log]` in that same config file - /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log on CentOS 7, e.g.

Comment: `sudo vi /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` for me

Comment: This was the right way for me, on Debian 9.1 and PHP-FPM 7.0

Comment: PHP is so confuse... there are a pre-created `/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log` so, `php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log` will redirect to non-standard log??

Comment: @SudharshanNair , I don't think so. Server should be able to handle rotation

Comment: @michaelbn. I have followed every mentioned step, Still its not logging errors. do I need to set anything in `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` ?

Comment: @SudharshanNair, no, if you haven't changed it. Just make sure that the file you edit is configured in `php-fpm.conf` as the desired pool.

Comment: @michaelbn. Currently in my `php-fpm.conf`, I can see this line `error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log`. So do i need to change here?

Comment: the path for me was `/etc/php/7.0/pool.d/www.conf`

Comment: Using NGINX and PHP7.2... Seems `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf`, **is it?**

Comment: In docker hub wordpress php-fpm docker images the conf is at `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf`

Answer (score 80):

I struggled with this for a long time before finding my php-fpm logs were being written to `/var/log/upstart/php5-fpm.log`. It appears to be a bug between how upstart and php-fpm interact. See more here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1319595

Comment: Thanks!! This was the key for me. I ended up symlinking the two files because I know I'm not going to remember this later: `ln -sf /var/log/upstart/php5-fpm.log /var/log/php5-fpm.log`

Comment: PHP is so confuse... there are a pre-created `/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log` so, `php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log` will redirect to non-standard log??

Answer (score 67):

I had a similar issue and had to do the following to the `pool.d/www.conf` file

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

It still wasn't writing the log file so I actually had to create it by `touch /var/log/fpm-php.www.log` then setting the correct owner `sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/log/fpm-php.www.log`.

Once this was done, and php5-fpm restarted, logging was resumed.

Comment: that was actually the case! I even got some futher content appeared on site right after error :)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This was the solution for me on Ubuntu 14.04.1 (Jessie), if it helps anyone else.

Comment: Some problem in a vagrant/debian wheezy environment.

Comment: Other paths, such as /var/log/, where just a waste of time.

Comment: Why?! This is still a problem on fpm-php7.

Comment: PHP is so confuse... there are a pre-created `/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log` so, `php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log` will redirect to non-standard log??

Comment: creating a subdirectory in /var/log, like "/var/log/fpm-php", then "chown www-data /var/log/fpm-php" (the user the nginx/php runs under),   and setting  "php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php/error.log" to a file in that subdir should help when rebooting or log rotationg. As the directory permission are preserved and nginx/php can create the log file (and /var/log/ is cleaner...)

Answer (score 36):

There are multiple php config files, but THIS is the one you need to edit:

```
/etc/php(version)?/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

uncomment the line that says:

```
catch_workers_output
```

That will allow PHPs stderr to go to php-fpm's error log instead of /dev/null.

Comment: For those using docker your config files are located: `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/`

Comment: With this conf, where goes the log,  at `/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log`, at  `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log` or other?

Comment: Where does it log to?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the www.conf file - the value of `php_admin_value[error_log]` shows where the log will be written to

Answer (score 30):

I gathered insights from a bunch of answers here and I present a comprehensive solution:

So, if you setup nginx with php5-fpm and log a message using `error_log()` you can see it in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` by default.

A problem can arise if you want to log a lot of data (say an array) using `error_log(print_r($myArr, true));`. If an array is large enough, it seems that `nginx` will truncate your log entry.

To get around this you can configure `fpm` ([php.net fpm config](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php)) to manage logs. Here are the steps to do so.

1. Open `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`:

   `$ sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
2. Uncomment the following two lines by removing `;` at the beginning of the line: (error_log is defined here: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log))

   `;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
   ;php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on`
3. Create `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log`:

   `$ sudo touch /var/log/fpm-php.www.log;`
4. Change ownership of `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log` so that php5-fpm can edit it:

   `$ sudo chown vagrant /var/log/fpm-php.www.log`

   Note: `vagrant` is the user that I need to give ownership to. You can see what user this should be for you by running `$ ps aux | grep php.*www` and looking at first column.
5. Restart php5-fpm:

   `$ sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Now your logs will be in `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log`.

Comment: I tried this, Still "fpm-php.www.log" is empty. Any idea?

Comment: Print your `phpinfo()` and see if these settings actually got picked up, @SudharshanNair.

Comment: @Gezim. thanks for your reply. my error log path is `/var/log/fpm-php.www.log`. Still this file is empty

Comment: @SudharshanNair, If `log_errors` errors is turned on the only other thing to check is permission and ownership of the file (step 4).

Comment: Ensure `www-data` is the user that the fpm process is running under: `ps aux | grep php.*www`. I don't have any other ideas. Comb through your output of `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Please tell me how I can change the `log_level` of the application without having to change the global file directive that has been added with php-fpm docker. Thank you very much.

Comment: another mystery on PHP-FPM https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1141, I don't know if I'm in time to migrate to another programming language, the PHP configuration never ends. It is horrendous.

Answer (score 15):

There is a bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61045 in php-fpm from v5.3.9 and till now (5.3.14 and 5.4.4). Developer promised fix will go live in next release. If you don't want to wait - use patch on that page and re-build or rollback to 5.3.8.

Answer (score 8):

In your fpm.conf file you haven't set 2 variable which are only for error logging.

The variables are `error_log` (file path of your error log file) and `log_level` (error logging level).

```
; Error log file
; Note: the default prefix is /usr/local/php/var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log

error_log = log/php-fpm.log

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice

log_level = notice
```

Comment: isn't the default `/usr/local/var/php` instead of `/usr/local/php/var`? just speculating.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add another tip to the existing answers because they did not solve my problem.

Watch out for the following nginx directive in your php location block:

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

Removing this line has brought an end to many hours of struggling and pulling hair.

It could be hidden in some included conf directory like `/etc/nginx/default.d/php.conf` in my fedora.

Answer (score 2):

in my case I show that the error log was going to */var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log* . so I commented this line in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
php_flag[display_errors]   is commented
php_flag[display_errors] = on  log will be at /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

and as said above I also uncommented this line

```
catch_workers_output = yes
```

Now I can see logs in the file specified by nginx.

Answer (score 0):

On alpine 3.15 with php8 i found on /var/log/php8/error.log

```
/var/log/php8 # cat error.log
 16:10:52] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 14
 16:10:52] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

i also have this :

```
catch_workers_output = yes
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case php-fpm outputs 500 error without any logging because of missing php-mysql module. I moved joomla installation to another server and forgot about it. So `apt-get install php-mysql` and service restart solved it.

I started with trying to fix broken logging without success. Finally with `strace` i found fail message after db-related system calls. Though my case is not directly related to op's question, I hope it could be useful.

Answer (score -6):

Check the Owner directory of "PHP-FPM"

You can do:

```
ls -lah /var/log/php-fpm/
chown -R webusr:webusr /var/log/php-fpm/
chmod -R 777 /var/log/php-fpm/
```

Comment: never set /var/log/php-fpm to 777, you just made your server vulnerable to a symlink attack (if not worse)