# nginx -> php5-fpm: Error in php not logged (anywhere!)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, phpbb3

I am attempting to set up phpbb on an EC2 server. After an hour or so of despair I found that a particular line in the phpbb startup is failing:

```
$db->sql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname, $dbport, false, defined('PHPBB_DB_NEW_LINK') ? PHPBB_DB_NEW_LINK : false);
```

Easy fix, I need to configure my DB properties properly.

*However*, to find that I had to insert echo '1' statements block by block throughout the first couple files of the php app. Prior to the echo statements, I'd get just a blank page, with status 200, when php errored out.

I've turned on both log_errors and display_errors in FPM's php.ini, but apparently they don't do anything with this particular type of error.

There are no logs about the error in /var/log/syslog, /var/log/nginx/*, /var/log/php-fpm.log, or the error log for the nginx site.

So, my question: why is the actual error (from sql_connect) not being logged anywhere? (Alternately, if it is being logged, where?)

Comment: Did you restart both php-fpm and nginx after editing configurations ?

Comment: @JohnWHS Yeah I've been consistently restarting them after making edits.

Comment: did you check the `error_log` settings inside `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` ? could be changed from the default path, you said ur error log was `php-fpm.log` while mine actually is `php5-fpm.log`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks - yeah I tried leaving them default (commented out) and setting them to a specific file name. Neither worked so far

Comment: What version of phpbb and what file is this? Quite possible the errors are being suppressed.

Comment: @Melvyn 3.11, and common.php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677493/php-fpm-doesnt-write-to-error-log?lq=1 (has more answers).

Answer (score 5):

search for `catch_workers_output` in your pool and set it to yes, from the doc:

```
 catch_workers_output - Redirect workers' stdout and stderr into main error log. If not set, they will be redirected to /dev/null, according to FastCGI specs. Values "yes" or "no"
```

**EDIT**:

also check you have

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
```

and/or

```
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = true
```

Comment: Wow that's a dumb default. Thanks - that was inevitably part of the issue (and/or would have tripped me up later.) However, still no joy (after restarting).

Comment: thanks, the edit made no difference either. I don't understand why the edit is necessary assuming that log_errors is turned on in php.ini, but in any case setting it didn't yield the log anywhere. I should also mention that if I turn display_errors on, this particular error doesn't get displayed either -- I guess that's consistent with the error occurring in a particular worker and not being routed correctly.

Comment: On line 100 of common.php is the code:

    set_error_handler(defined('PHPBB_MSG_HANDLER') ? PHPBB_MSG_HANDLER : 'msg_handler');

If I comment that out, trigger_error before the sql connect statement shows up. The sql connect error still does not show up anywhere.

Comment: phpbb has its own error handling features, from the doc somewhere I read "The Error Log is created automatically inside the /store/ directory, and will be called php_error.log ", check there or try to set DEBUG True in your config.php.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today.  What I discovered is that the permissions for my log file were incorrect.  Ownership was assigned to root.  I did a `chmod 777 php5-fpm.log` to confirm that was the issue and it was. Logging worked after that.

I did a `chown syslog:adm php5-fpm.log` to set the correct ownership.