# Nginx + FastCGI + PHP (php-fpm) not logging caught errors/warnings

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

FastCGI doesn't want to log PHP errors properly.  Well, that's not entirely true: it logs errors fine, with a little fiddling; it just won't log anything else, such as warnings.

The notorious FastCGI -> Nginx log bug isn't an issue, necessarily.  Errors and warnings from php-fpm go straight to Nginx--but only if they're uncaught.  That is, if `set_error_handler` successfully intercepts an error, no log entry is appended.  This means that I can see parse errors, but that's about it.

php-fpm doesn't log PHP errors by itself (separate from nginx) without a bit of a hack.  php-fpm's instance configuration file includes these two lines by default:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /mnt/log/php-fpm/default.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

I changed the error_log path, obviously.  I had to add the following line to get it to actually log anything:

```
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Version note: the E_STRICT part is unnecessary, as I'm using PHP 5.3.27, but I plan on upgrading to 5.4 at some point.  With this line, it logs errors--and only errors--to `/mnt/log/php-fpm/default.log`.  Now, this sets `error_reporting` to the same value that I have set in php.ini, so something is obviously wrong here.  In addition, it doesn't log caught errors: the behavior is identical to that of the nginx log.  I tried using the numeric value (22527) instead, but still no luck.

I don't care in which log file the entries end up (nginx versus php-fpm), but I do need caught errors to be logged somewhere.  I could resort to injecting my own error and exception handlers, but that's a bit hackish, so I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: Am I crazy in recalling that Apache didn't have this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this directive in the pool configuration file for PHP-FPM:

> `catch_workers_output = yes`

Comment: I have that set, but it's still not logging the caught errors.

Comment: @Zenexer have you checked permissions on the directories and files used in logging? They should probably be owned by `root`; `chmod 0755` on directories and `chmod 0644` on files.

Comment: Yeah, the permissions are fine.  Everything is owned by nginx and running as nginx.  It writes stuff, just not everything.  I think I'm just expecting a behavior that isn't meant to be exhibited.  Apache does the same thing.

Comment: @Zenexer it turns out there was a PHP bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11250412/1429647

Comment: Nah, I'm on 5.5.x.  Turns out vBulletin was just intercepting everything and dumping it, which I should've guessed.

Comment: This is certainly a common answer to the question, so I'm going to mark it as the answer, seeing as it ended up being something irrelevant.