# Why PHP-FPM prefixes a warning when writing to stdout?

Tags: php, docker

I try to run a [Yii based PHP application](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-dockerized) in a Docker container using the [official php-fpm](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) image.

It's common practice for docker containers to write all log messages to `stdout` / `stderr`. So I do the same from my container with a code that basically looks like this:

```
$fp = @fopen('php://stdout','w');
fwrite($fp, $message);
fclose($fp);
```

Unfortunately PHP-FPM now prefixes all my log messages with ugly warnings:

> [21-Mar-2016 14:10:02] WARNING: [pool www] child 12 said into stdout:     "2016-03-21 14:10:02 [x.x.x.x][-][-][trace][yii\base\Application::bootstrap] Bootstrap with yii\debug\Module::bootstrap()"
>   [21-Mar-2016 14:10:02] WARNING: [pool www] child 12 said into stdout: "2016-03-21 14:10:02 [x.x.x.x][-][-][info][yii\web\Session::open] Session started"
>   ...

Why is this and is there a way to prevent PHP-FPM from doing this?

UPDATE:

1. I've also opened [an issue](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/207) at the [docker-library/php](https://github.com/docker-library/php) project site.
2. They already include the `catch_workers_output = yes` in [their configuration](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/d7176685dfad98d1e472557b10534c89fb0693ec/5.6/fpm/Dockerfile#L99). So that's not the solution.
3. According to [these changes](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2458) the problem should be fixed in PHP 7.3

Comment: I think that it's a common bug https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/63 that it was fixed in version 44, can you confirm ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis Can't confirm. As you should see from the problem description I don't use heroku. It's more a misbehaviour of php-fpm in general.

Comment: You tried playing with the `catch_workers_output` option in your `php.ini`? Not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: hope this thread might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546138/4098311

Comment: @HalayemAnis Thanks, I've seen that. This configuration is already in place in the official docker image (https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/d7176685dfad98d1e472557b10534c89fb0693ec/5.6/fpm/Dockerfile#L99). Unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: There's been an update to your [Github issue](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/207) this week, any luck with that solution?

Comment: @miken32 I didn't try it. There are other workarounds, all require you to mess around with `CMD` - something I don't want to do.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl, Hats off to your efforts, I just seen on : https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/207

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. you are running php-fpm and error logs are from php-fpm , not from PHP .
you should expect php-fpm log , not php log. fortunately php-fpm will write every log that received from PHP in end of its logs.

Answer (score 0):

Above Php7.3 [Use](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/207#issuecomment-446547341) `decorate_workers_output = no` in php.conf