# log to stdout / stderr with Laravel 5.6 and php-fpm

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.6

I want my laravel applications to run as well mannered 12 factor apps. Right now I'm struggling to get their to logs to and from `stdout` (`stderr` is also fine by me) under php-fpm. The php version is 7.2.1, the laravel version is 5.6.3.

I configured laravel to use the `single` driver to write to stdout:

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),
    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single'],
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => 'php://stdout',
            'tap' => [App\Logging\UseJsonFormatter::class],
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
];
```

This works well with the test server, but fpm prefixes this with with dates and a warning: `[19-Feb-2018 09:43:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 12 said into stdout:` every ~1000 characters.
The problem seems to be known as [issue 71880 (prefix)](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71880) and [issue 69031 (truncation)](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69031). A [Pull Request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2458) saw last action in June / November last year. Does anybody have a workaround that doesn't chunk or truncate the log messages (I'm logging json objects, and I like them complete)?

[Why PHP-FPM prefixes a warning when writing to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134167/why-php-fpm-prefixes-a-warning-when-writing-to-stdout) is related to this, but is still not solved either.

This is UseJsonFormatter.php if anyone is interested:

```
<?php    
namespace App\Logging;


use Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter;

class UseJsonFormatter
{
    /**
     * Customize the given Monolog instance.
     *
     * @param  \Monolog\Logger  $monolog
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($monolog)
    {
        $jsonFormatter = new JsonFormatter();
        foreach ($monolog->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            $handler->setFormatter($jsonFormatter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing logs to `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` instead?

Comment: @Mike I have and laravel reports both as missing: `The stream or file "/dev/stderr" could not be opened: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed in PHP 7.3. 
The config directive for the pool is `decorate_workers_output = no` as documented in the [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2458#issuecomment-415224509).

Answer (score 3):

With Monolog in general, if you want to keep for instance **DEBUG** to **INFO** messages in **STDOUT** and higher levels to **STDERR**, you could do something like this.

```
$log->pushHandler(
    new \Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler(
        new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout'),
            \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG,
            \Monolog\Logger::NOTICE
    )
);

$log->pushHandler(
    new \Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler(
        new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stderr'),
            \Monolog\Logger::WARNING,
            \Monolog\Logger::EMERGENCY
    )
);
```

Comment: Where do I need to place this?

Comment: @Kaymaz: Anywhere you have access to the logger object, but preferable close to where you instantiate your logger object so you have it setup this way as early as possible.