# phpMyAdmin 4.6.2 token mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm getting the dreaded "token mismatch" error on my phpMyAdmin. My install lives in a vagrant/ansible box so it is a clean system.

If I have auth_type set to "cookie" I simply stay on the login page and if I set it to "http" I get the "token mismatch" error.

phpMyAdmin config.inc.php

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '123'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! 
$i = 0;
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http'; // or cookie
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Nginx config:

```
server
  {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name dev.company.local _;

  root /var/www/sites/dev.company.local;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.company.local-access.log combined;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/dev.company.local-error.log notice;
  index index.html index.php;

  include fastcgi_portal.conf;

  location /phpmyadmin/(.*) {
        alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
  }

  }
```

I won't post my php.ini here as it such a huge file but few options are configured.

Things I've already checked:

- `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440`
- `session.save_path = /var/lib/php/session` (set to 777, also tried `/tmp`)
- mcrypt is enabled
- clearing browser cookies etc
- verified my mysql credentials
- set the correct time + timezone of the VM

I found bug reports like https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3893/ but for me it does not seem to be fixed :)

Other info:

- `CentOS release 6.7 (Final)`
- `nginx version: nginx/1.0.15`
- `PHP 5.6.22 (fpm-fcgi) (built: May 26 2016 15:45:15)`

I've tried the current phpMyAdmin version (4.6.2), the previous version (4.6.1) and the long-term version (4.4.15.6) all the same.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are there any errors in the PHP/webserver logs?

Comment: @MichalČihař no, nothing in both php-fpm and nginx error log

Comment: Does the browser accept cookies from phpMyAdmin? Reading again the descripton this seems to be the issue - cookie authentication can not store credentials, but with http one you get token mismatch as the CSRF token is stored in cookies....

Comment: @MichalČihař As far as I can tell the browser is accepting cookies. I did not set it to deny and it happens also in other browsers than Chrome

Comment: In past we had some problems in calculating cookie path, but AFAIR it was on Windows, but please check if it is set correctly...

Comment: @MichalČihař What exactly do you mean? Is this a phpMyAdmin setting? Or are you pointing to the php sessions dir?

Comment: Open developer console in your browser and check what path is set for cookies.

Comment: The path is "/phpmyadmin/"

Comment: That sounds correct as well. So the problem might be on the PHP side not finding the sessions...

Comment: Than I would assume an error is displayed in the log? However I don't think this can be it. I've set the `session.save_path` to different directories and tested different file modes. Even when set to "/tmp" with "777" as permission it doesn't work.

Comment: For PHP-FPM the logging is a bit tricky, you might need to set ```catch_workers_output = yes```, see  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546138/225718

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Docker in Vagrant, then it's most likely  caused by https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/32.

It can be fixed by simply pulling newer version of the container :-).

Comment: No, it is a vagrant box I've configured with some ansible scripts. (and for the phpmyadmin part it is simply getting the zip and extracting it)

Answer (score 1):

I got *exactly* the same problem as you describe after security hardening of my Apache.
In my case it turned out to be the following that broke phpMyAdmin:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

After commenting it out and restarting httpd everything worked again.

Supposedly the above header setting is to mitigate most of the common Cross Site Scripting attack using HttpOnly and Secure flag in a cookie but looks like PMA developers have not fully considered this scenario.